# затемнение div при нажатии кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Имею код на js:

```
$("button").click(function () {
$("div").toggleClass("shadow");
})
```

css:

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ff0;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
}
```

У меня вопрос как можно здесь привязать это к конкретному div и кнопке?(id нет, только названия класса) и откликивание происходило при нажатии на весь div. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Включаем div только по кнопке. Выключаем div по кнопке и div.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $("div").toggleClass("shadow");
});
$('div').on('click', function() {
  $(this).removeClass("shadow");
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ff0;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Кнопка</button>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте привязку к классу div. И вместо функции `$("button").click(function () {` можно использовать `$('.shadow').on('click', function() {`

```js
    $('.shadow').on('click', function() {
        $("div").toggleClass("shadow");
    })
```

```css
    div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: #ff0;
        margin: 50px auto;
    }
    .shadow {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shadow">Именно нажатие на весь div, а не кнопки.<button>Тык</button></div>
```

Comment: надо чтобы, например, включается только по кнопке(не по div), а выключается по всему div